# migrating information off a windows 8.1 tablet to a network sql server

Tags: sql-server, sqlite, tablet

I need to communicate back and forth from a network sql server to a sqlite db located on a tablet. Does anybody know of anyway to do this? I need to send a row of data to include an image to the sql server and be able to allow people on the network side to delete data off of the tablet. I've tried installing sqlite-sync software but I don't think the people behind the website have abandoned it. Any help would be much appreciated just point me in the right direction.

thanks

Comment: Is this for a Windows Store app, or a traditional desktop app? What programming language are you using?

Comment: I've programmed this in windows 8.1 as a winrt metro app to be able to be store certified if that's what you mean, I'm using c#.net